# Set root activity/intent in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I'm switching between different Activities using Intents. For one Activity, I would like it to clear the history stack so when the user presses the back button, it takes them Home instead of previous activities in my application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to implement the same thing for my project. What I ended up doing was to replace:
  startActivity(i); with startActivityForResult(i, UniqueId); in all the activities I wanted to be part of the "history stack".

Then implemented:

```
setResult(UniqueId);
finish();
```

in the child activity when I wanted to close the child and return to "home/root".

In the parent activity, I implemented:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == UniqueId && resultCode == UniqueId) {
 setResult(UniqueId);
 finish();
}
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Which effectively means if the child activity sent a "home/root" result (represented by UniqueId), all parents of that child activity that have used "startActivityForResult(i, UniqueId);" will close as well.

Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

You could try calling `finish()` on the activities you don't want to keep around when calling `startActivity`?

Or, the less android solution, listen for `onBackPressed()` in your activities and then call `startActivity()` on your main activity with the `CLEAR_STACK` flag set.

Comment: How would I call `finish()` on them? I don't have references to them.

Comment: Falmarri means you call 
startActivity(intent);
finish(); Ant it works.